# HTML form submit button refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web, registration

I'm currently writing a registration form in HTML and have come across a couple of problems. Firstly, I have to have a separate button outside of the form tags to run the function as my submit button just submits the form whether input fields are entered incorrectly, only showing the validation alerts for a split second. Secondly, if I enter the email correctly it states that 'email.includes' is not valid, however, it still runs as it should, this error does not appear if I enter an invalid email. Thanks for any answers (I know my code is not great, I'm still learning a lot)

```js
function validate_form() {
  var forename = document.getElementById("forename");
  var surname = document.getElementById("surname");
  var username = document.getElementById("username");
  var password = document.getElementById("password");
  var re_password = document.getElementById("re_password");
  var email = document.getElementById("email");
  var errors = 0
  var special_chars = "<>@!#$%^&*()_+[]{}?:;|'\"\\,./~`-=";

  if (forename.value == "") {
    //document.getElementById("forename").style.background = "red";
    forename_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var errors = errors + 1
  } else
    for (var i = 0; i < forename.value.length; i++) {
      if (special_chars.indexOf(forename.value.charAt(i)) != -1) {
        forename_chars.style.visibility = 'visible'
      }
    }

  if (surname.value == "") {
    //document.getElementById("surname").style.background = "red";
    surname_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var errors = errors + 1
  } else
    for (var i = 0; i < surname.value.length; i++) {
      if (special_chars.indexOf(surname.value.charAt(i)) != -1) {
        surname_chars.style.visibility = 'visible'
      }
    }

  if (username.value == "") {
    //document.getElementById("username").style.background = "red";
    username_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var errors = errors + 1
  } else
    for (var i = 0; i < username.value.length; i++) {
      if (special_chars.indexOf(username.value.charAt(i)) != -1) {
        username_chars.style.visibility = 'visible'
      }
    }

  if (password.value == "") {
    //document.getElementById("password").style.background = "red";
    pass_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var errors = errors + 1
  }

  if (password.value != re_password.value) {
    //document.getElementById("re_password").style.background = "red";
    repass_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var errors = errors + 1
  }

  if (email.value == "") {
    //document.getElementById("email").style.background = "red";
    var errors = errors + 1
  }

  if (errors != "0") {
    alert("Whoops! Looks like you didn't enter your details properly")
  }
  if (!email.value.includes("@") || !email.includes(".")) {
    //document.getElementById("email").style.background = "blue";
    email_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    return false;
  }
  return (true);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Login form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Login Form CSS.css">
  <script src="Registration function.js" defer></script>

  <body>
    <div class="loginbox">
      <img src="Logo.jpg" class="avatar">
      <h1> Create Account </h1>
      <form name="login-form">
        <div id="forename_confirmation"> Please fill in this box </div>
        <div id="forename_chars"> Don't use special characters</div>
        <p>Forename
          <p>
            <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" placeholder="Enter Forename here">
            <div id="surname_confirmation"> Please fill in this box </div>
            <div id="surname_chars"> Don't use special characters</div>
            <p>Surname
              <p>
                <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Enter Surname here">
                <div id="username_confirmation"> Please fill in this box </div>
                <div id="username_chars"> Don't use special characters</div>
                <p>Username
                  <p>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username here">
                    <div id="pass_confirmation"> Please fill in this box </div>
                    <div id="pass_chars">Don't use special characters</div>
                    <p>Password
                      <p>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password here">
                        <div id="repass_confirmation"> Passwords do not match </div>
                        <p>Re-enter Password
                          <p>
                            <input type="password" name="re_password" id="re_password" placeholder="Re-enter your password here">
                            <div id="email_confirmation"> Please enter a valid email </div>
                            <p>Email
                              <p>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email here">
                                <!-- 
                  <p>Gender<p>
                  <input type="radio" id="Male" name="Gender" value="Male">Male</input>
                  <input type="radio" id="Female" name="Gender" value="Female">Female</input>
                  -->
                                <button onclick="validate_form()" type="Submit" value="True" name="button-submit"> Submit </button>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <a href="#"> Forgot your password? </a>
                                <br />
                                <a href="#"> Already got an account? </a>
                                <br /><br />
      </form>
      <!-- <button onclick="validate_form()" type="submit"> Validate </button> -->
    </div>
  </body>
</head>
<script>
  forename_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  forename_chars.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  surname_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  surname_chars.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  username_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  username_chars.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  pass_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  pass_chars.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  repass_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  email_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to add the action attribute to your form, Check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues here:

When you don't want to submit your form (e. g. entered details are incorrect), you will need to prevent it from submitting. In JavaScript, you can to this with `preventDefault()`.

So achieve this, I added the line `event.preventDefault()` to your `if statement` that checks if there are any errors. Keep in mind that you need to pass the `event` parameter to your function in order to get `preventDefault()` working.

---

Secondly, you need to check if the `value` of your email field `includes` something.

You got your email field like this: `var email = document.getElementById('email');`, so you need to check the `value` like this: `email.value.includes('bla')`.

---

All together, your script works perfectly fine:

```js
function validate_form(event) {
  var forename = document.getElementById("forename");
  var surname = document.getElementById("surname");
  var username = document.getElementById("username");
  var password = document.getElementById("password");
  var re_password = document.getElementById("re_password");
  var email = document.getElementById("email");
  var errors = 0
  var special_chars = "<>@!#$%^&*()_+[]{}?:;|'\"\\,./~`-=";

  if (forename.value == "") {
    //document.getElementById("forename").style.background = "red";
    forename_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var errors = errors + 1
  } else
    for (var i = 0; i < forename.value.length; i++) {
      if (special_chars.indexOf(forename.value.charAt(i)) != -1) {
        forename_chars.style.visibility = 'visible'
      }
    }

  if (surname.value == "") {
    //document.getElementById("surname").style.background = "red";
    surname_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var errors = errors + 1
  } else
    for (var i = 0; i < surname.value.length; i++) {
      if (special_chars.indexOf(surname.value.charAt(i)) != -1) {
        surname_chars.style.visibility = 'visible'
      }
    }

  if (username.value == "") {
    //document.getElementById("username").style.background = "red";
    username_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var errors = errors + 1
  } else
    for (var i = 0; i < username.value.length; i++) {
      if (special_chars.indexOf(username.value.charAt(i)) != -1) {
        username_chars.style.visibility = 'visible'
      }
    }

  if (password.value == "") {
    //document.getElementById("password").style.background = "red";
    pass_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var errors = errors + 1
  }

  if (password.value != re_password.value) {
    //document.getElementById("re_password").style.background = "red";
    repass_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var errors = errors + 1
  }

  if (email.value == "") {
    //document.getElementById("email").style.background = "red";
    var errors = errors + 1
  }

  if (errors != "0") {
    alert("Whoops! Looks like you didn't enter your details properly");
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting
  }
  if (!email.value.includes("@") || !email.value.includes(".")) {
    //document.getElementById("email").style.background = "blue";
    email_confirmation.style.visibility = 'visible';
    return false;
  }
  return (true);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Login form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Login Form CSS.css">
  <script src="Registration function.js" defer></script>

  <body>
    <div class="loginbox">
      <img src="Logo.jpg" class="avatar">
      <h1> Create Account </h1>
      <form name="login-form">
        <div id="forename_confirmation"> Please fill in this box </div>
        <div id="forename_chars"> Don't use special characters</div>
        <p>Forename
          <p>
            <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" placeholder="Enter Forename here">
            <div id="surname_confirmation"> Please fill in this box </div>
            <div id="surname_chars"> Don't use special characters</div>
            <p>Surname
              <p>
                <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Enter Surname here">
                <div id="username_confirmation"> Please fill in this box </div>
                <div id="username_chars"> Don't use special characters</div>
                <p>Username
                  <p>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username here">
                    <div id="pass_confirmation"> Please fill in this box </div>
                    <div id="pass_chars">Don't use special characters</div>
                    <p>Password
                      <p>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password here">
                        <div id="repass_confirmation"> Passwords do not match </div>
                        <p>Re-enter Password
                          <p>
                            <input type="password" name="re_password" id="re_password" placeholder="Re-enter your password here">
                            <div id="email_confirmation"> Please enter a valid email </div>
                            <p>Email
                              <p>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email here">
                                <!-- 
                  <p>Gender<p>
                  <input type="radio" id="Male" name="Gender" value="Male">Male</input>
                  <input type="radio" id="Female" name="Gender" value="Female">Female</input>
                  -->
                                <button onclick="validate_form(event)" type="Submit" value="True" name="button-submit"> Submit </button>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <a href="#"> Forgot your password? </a>
                                <br />
                                <a href="#"> Already got an account? </a>
                                <br /><br />
      </form>
      <!-- <button onclick="validate_form()" type="submit"> Validate </button> -->
    </div>
  </body>
</head>
<script>
  forename_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  forename_chars.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  surname_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  surname_chars.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  username_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  username_chars.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  pass_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  pass_chars.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  repass_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  email_confirmation.style.visibility = 'hidden'
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment! The code is now working fine.

Comment: @Brig I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

If there is an validation error you need to prevent the event default behavior in order to prevent the browser from redirecting to target page (what you specified in the action attribute, or reloading the current page if not specified):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Your second question: I guess its email.value.includes (as you already used in your code on an other point) and you whant to check the value not the HTML-Node itself.
You might also want to look in email regex validation which would match the requirements of an email validation way better than checking for "@" an "." e.g. https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php